# Refresh User Control with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net, user-controls

I have a User Control which renders a simple drop downList into the page.

By default, only certain values are returned depending on User Details, but the user may request a "full" list.

I'd like this full list to be generated by pressing a reload button.

Being new to .NET I am struggling to get this to work and not really understand the results I get when Googling or finding stuff on this site. Is Classic ASP I'd have made a page that renders this and called it using jQuery

What I want to do is:

```
    $('.loadMore').live('click', function () {
        $('#listContainer').load('/Controls/List.ascx');
    });
```

But this returns an error in Firebug saying `"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden"`

I don't particularly want to use an updatepanel.

I've found this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117475/Load-ASP-Net-User-Control-Dynamically-Using-jQuery but am unsure exactly what it is suggesting, mainly I think, because I use VB and don't completely understand how to convert that C# code there.

Using .NET 2.0, jQuery and VB, does anyone have any suggestions on the simplest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does a conversion help you:

```
Public Class jQueryHandler
    Implements IHttpHandler
    Public Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext)
        ' We add control in Page tree collection
        Using dummyPage = New Page()
            dummyPage.Controls.Add(GetControl(context))
            context.Server.Execute(dummyPage, context.Response.Output, True)
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Function GetControl(context As HttpContext) As Control
        ' URL path given by load(fn) method on click of button
        Dim strPath As String = context.Request.Url.LocalPath
        Dim userctrl As UserControl = Nothing
        Using dummyPage = New Page()
            userctrl = TryCast(dummyPage.LoadControl(strPath), UserControl)
        End Using
        ' Loaded user control is returned
        Return userctrl
    End Function

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean
        Get
            Return True
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Yes, that does help, at least I can use it now. I'm still not sure what it does though. Would I be right in assuming that the dummyPage variable in there is effectively creating an HTML output on the fly and then posting that back to the browser? Would I be able to pass a variable as a querystring? I'll have a play with it....

Comment: With a bit of fiddling, that worked! I had to modify 2 lines, `Public Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest` and `Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable` needed to replace the declarations in the example above, but excellent... that works. I'm having another issue now; the User Control returns a drop down list. Firebug is returning the error "Element must be within a <form runat="server">" tag, but of course, if I wrap my User Control into such a tag in won't render in a page which already has a form tag.

Comment: Add another question: re: better way to manage a dynamic select list using jQuery and a web service and reference this question. Put your markup and code in that question so folks can see where you get your list populated from.

Comment: Thanks Mark, done, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388627/re-better-way-to-manage-a-dynamic-select-list-using-jquery-and-user-control