# Returning output of User Control as HTML or string with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, code-behind

This morning I was trying to work out how to update a User Control from a button on a page using jQuery.

I posted this question

[Refresh User Control with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386766/refresh-user-control-with-jquery)

From the info gleaned from this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117475/Load-ASP-Net-User-Control-Dynamically-Using-jQuery

And the excellent help I received following posting that question, I now have a method of loading a User Control as a page with jQuery using the converted .VB example from the codeproject.com article.

However... this won't render into the browser, Firebug is giving the error "element must be contained within a form runat=server tag"

So I posted this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388627/re-better-way-to-manage-a-dynamic-select-list-using-jquery-and-user-control

Since posting that though, I have thought about it further, and believe it is the fact that the `jQueryHandler` class created by the codeproject code is send the browser a complete page.

Given that I sadly don't really understand what that codeproject code actually does I am having trouble working out how to alter it.

What I need it to do is not return a Page at all, but I guess, an HTML string, which can then be pasted directly as HTML into the div as required.

Any ideas as to how to alter that code to return an HTML string?

(I am using asp.net 2.0 and VB)

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you are not handling this change with a postback?

Comment: Not as such. I'm new to .net, so not sure the best way to approach things. However, I don't want to use an update panel, or have a full page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

The postback would cause a full page refresh. Since you are wanting to avoid that then what I would recommend is this use jquery and dynamically create the options html and bind that to a click event

in the user control just type a reference to a js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/userControl.js"></script>

//set the page elements that you want rendered that will exists in every location that the user control is rendered.

<div>
  //Set your layout
  .
  .
  .
  //set the container for the dynamically chaning content
  <div id="dynamicContent"></div>
  <input type="button" id="ClickMe" />
</div>
```

In the script file you can then do something like this

```
$(document).Ready(function() {
  $("#ClickMe").click(GenerateContent)
});

function GenerateContent()
{
  var dynamicHTML;
  //condition == whatever conditions you are trying to validate to change the content
  if(condition)
  {
    dynamicHTML = ""; //set page specific content
  }
  $(dynamicHTML).appendTo("#dynamicContent");
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm not sure that will do it. The contents of the User Control is a dropDownList which is populated by code-behind from a database, results dependant on a variable passed into the Control (which is to be changed by the jQuery refresh) This would work if you could tell me how to "reload" the code-behind with jQuery to re-query the database etc... which actually is another issue I need for another problem I haven't dealt with yet!!!

Comment: actually that's not hard to do at all.  You just have to create a webservice and then bind an ajax call to the click event.  Pass in the information that you want and then look for the response.

Comment: Argh... I don't know how to use web services either, been trying to avoid it! More googling I guess!!

Comment: well it's either learn the web services, and ajax calls to them and then dynamically create the content based on the response or deal with the full page post back which does the same thing but isn't as elegant

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I looked into Web Services too, but decided after hours of faffing around to do away with a User Control all together and populate the dropdown list with a JSON file and jQuery